# Meteor/Neo4j creates two nodes when only one is requested

Tags: meteor, neo4j

I have created a bare-bones application with Meteor to understand how Neo4j and Meteor can work together, using the [Neo4j Reactivity driver](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/ostrio-Neo4jreactivity) for Meteor by Dmitriy Aristarkhovich.

When I use the web client to add a new node to the Neo4j database, I see two nodes appear in the Neo4j browser at `localhost:7474`. These nodes have the same `_id` but a different `id`. I do not set either "_id" or "id" anywhere, so presumably this is something that is added somewhere between Meteor, the various Neo4j wrappers and drivers, and Neo4j itself.

One node is shown with as having a "label", the other is not.

Here is my ASCII art for what appears in the Graph view, after I create a node with the name "Room 1" and the label "Room".

```
[*(2)]   [Room(1)]

(Room 1)
<id>:73 name:Room 1 _id:hLNZfesRg8mtPtyLW

(  75  )
<id>:75 name:Room 1 _id:hLNZfesRg8mtPtyLW
```

Here is what appears in the Rows view:

```
name    Room 1
_id hLNZfesRg8mtPtyLW

name    Room 1
_id hLNZfesRg8mtPtyLW
```

Here's the code:
HTML

```
<body>
  {{> addRoom}}
</body>

<template name="addRoom">
  <h3>Add a Room</h3>
  <input id="newRoomName" placeholder="Type name here"> 
  <button class="button" id="addRoom">Add Room</button>
</template>
```

JavaScript

```
var Rooms = Meteor.neo4j.collection("Rooms") // any collection name
var roomKey = "Rooms" // any publish-subscribe name

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var roomQuery = "MATCH (room:Room) RETURN room"
  Rooms.publish(roomKey, publishRoomQuery)

  function publishRoomQuery(){
    return roomQuery
  }
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun(function trackDataChanges(){
    var options = null // becomes `this` in the publishRoomQuery() 
    var link = "room" // object name, to link as MongoDB row(s).
    var subscription = Rooms.subscribe(roomKey, options, link)
  })

  Template.addRoom.events({
    'click #addRoom': function () {
      var $input = $('#newRoomName')
      var roomName = $input.val()

      if(roomName){
        Rooms.insert({ // THE LINE THAT CALLS NEO4J
          name: roomName,
          __labels: ':Room'
        });
        $input.val('');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Is this behaviour what I should expect? Am I misunderstanding something basic? Or does this suggest that there is a bug in the modules that connect with Neo4j from Meteor?

Note: I've written up the way I installed all the dependencies for my application [here](http://lexogram.github.io/Meteo4j/#dependencies), but I'm not convinced that this is where the issue lies.

---

EDIT

@MichaelHunger

I have added the following code to the `Meteor.isServer` section:

```
  var constraint = "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (room:Room) ASSERT room.name IS UNIQUE"
  Meteor.N4JDB.query(constraint, null, constraintCallback)

  function constraintCallback(error, data){
    console.log(error, data)
  }
```

However, I still see two nodes being created from the Meteor app. Everything works as expected, though, when I run this query in the Neo4j browser at `localhost:7474`:

```
CREATE (r:Room {name: "Room2"}) RETURN r
// /!\  Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintViolation
// Node 80 already exists with label Room and property "name"=[Room 1]
```

So it looks as if the constraint is being set correctly, but the Neo4j Reactivity Driver is somehow bypassing the constraint.

Comment: Hi James, Not sure if it helps but did you create a unique constraint for `create constraint on (r:Room) assert r.name is unique` ?

Comment: Hi James, I confirm - it is a bug, I'll publish fix to atmosphere in next 36 hours.

Comment: @dr.dimitru Thanks for your reactivity.